# How to use <LinkControl />

Tags: customization, block-editor, links

I am a **beginner in WordPress development** looking to build a block with tab navigation using `<LinkControl />`. I am still learning, so any guidance/materials/code examples will be appreciated.

My question is, if I have multiple `<LinkControl />`, how would I check the current index of that `<LinkControl />` in order to set the attributes?

Here is my code in `index.js`:

```
const amountDefault = [
  {
    title: 'Link 1',
    url: '#',
    opensInNewTab: false,
    id: 0,
  },
  {
    title: 'Link 2',
    url: 'https://www.google.com',
    opensInNewTab: false,
    id: 1,
  },
  {
    title: 'Link 3',
    url: 'https://www.amazon.co.uk',
    opensInNewTab: false,
    id: 2,
  },
];
const blockAttributes = {
  items: {
    type: 'array',
    default: amountDefault,
  },
};
registerBlockType('my-theme/nav-bar', {
  title: __('Nav bar', 'my-theme'),
  icon: 'welcome-add-page',
  category: 'layout',
  supports: {
    multiple: true,
  },
  attributes: blockAttrs,
```

and here is the code for my edit function:

```
const { items } = attributes;
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <p>Test2</p>
        <nav>
          <ul>{listItems}</ul>
        </nav>
        <p>Testing Link Control</p>
        {items.map((item, index) => (
          <LinkControl
            value={{ url: item.url, title: item.title, opensInNewTab: item.opensInNewTab }}
            onChange={value => {
// create link manager for each item
// when clicking on 'edit' on item - replace the value with the new value

            }}
          />
        ))}
```

I am not sure how to reference that particular item in my array in order change edit the link - could someone help me please?

Comment: This is actually a JS question, but anyway, in that `onChange()` function, you could use the `findIndex()` function in JS `Array`. E.g. To find by the link `id`, you can use `let index = amountDefault.findIndex( obj => value.id === obj.id );` and if the value is `0` or greater (i.e. `index >= 0`), then that means the item/link was found in your `amountDefault` array.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying and apologies asking in this forum (thank you for being nice about it) - I was at a loss and wasn't sure the best place for this question. Thanks for explaining how to find the value in the array - how would I set the attribute if the link that I am changing to has a different ID e.g. my array ID = 1, but the value.id is 2?

Comment: If I understand it correctly, you just need to find the index in the `items` array in your edit function and update the item at that index (i.e. merge the `value` with the one currently in the `items`), then do something like `setAttributes( { items } )`. E.g. `const index = items.findIndex( obj => value.id === obj.id ); items[ index ] = { ...items[ index ], ...value }; setAttributes( { items } );`

Comment: @SallyCJ i'm not sure I understand what you mean with the code snippet above - if I have a list of `LinkControl`s, I would like to know which one I have selected to edit, and then set the attribute for that specific `LinkControl`. I tested the snippet and I only get the ID of the URL I am changing to

Comment: I included a modified version of that snippet in my answer. I hope that helps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the `LinkControl` index is already there in your code.. it's in the `items.map( ( item, index ) )` — yes, that `index`. So just use it in your `onChange` callback.

And presuming that your edit function starts like `( { attributes, setAttributes } ) => { ...`, i.e. the `setAttributes` is defined, you can try the following in place of what you currently have:

```js
items.map( ( item, index ) => (
    <LinkControl
        value={ { ...item } }
        onChange={ ( value ) => {
            // do not change the existing 'items' array; clone it instead
            const newItems = [ ...items ];

            // then update the one being edited
            // the 'index' below is the one passed to .map() above
            newItems[ index ] = { ...newItems[ index ], ...value };

            // then update the block attributes
            setAttributes( { items: newItems } );

            console.log( value, newItems, items ); // for testing/debugging
        } }
    />
) )
```

Comment: Thank you!! The comments are a great help as well!

Comment: I'm glad I could help. :) Happy coding!

Comment: PS: I meant, "passed *by* `.map()`", not "passed to `.map()`"

Comment: If I wanted to edit the link but wanted to have the `edit link `functionality and the `open in a new tab` toggle to be in its own modal/popup, how can this be implemented?

Comment: Sorry, but you'll need to ask that in a separate question - and *if* I can, I'd try to help you. :) Nonetheless, you might want to check [`URLPopover`](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/tree/master/packages/block-editor/src/components/url-popover).